# Eclipse @author tag refactoring over project

Tags: eclipse, syntax, documentation

I have completed a project with my author tag as UserA (Default naming by eclipse as my desktop user is named "UserA")

Therefore over the classes in my whole project, the author is "UserA"

Is there a way to change this name in the classes that have already been completed?

I know you can change the name so that new classes will adhere to the new name, but what about older classes already created.

Answer (score 0):

Do a **File Search** with the **Replace..** option

You can get to the **File Search** wizard by choosing **Search->File...** from the Eclipse top menu

In the dialog box, you'll want something similar to these parameters:

**Containing text:** `@author UserA`

**File name patterns (separated by comma):** *.java

Then click the **Replace...** button instead of Search

It will perform the search and then prompt you for the replacement text once the search is completed. Use something like `@author UserB` as your replacement text.